# does an imported function from a module could access class from this module?

Tags: python-3.x, module

I am a new comer when it comes to package and module to python.
I am trying to cut my script in several separate compartiment. to improve readability and maintenance.

My problem is the following:

I have a module which define a class and a function inside this module which instantiate this class.
module blast.py

```
class Blast():
    blabla

def foo():
    blast = Blast()
    # do some stuff
```

this module is inside a package with a _ _init__.py file

```
__all__ = ["blast"]
```

I have a main script In which i want to use that function.
I import the module with

```
from package import blast
```

But To use that function I have to  use the name space of the module ( at least my IDE say me that: pycharm)

```
blast.foo()
```

So does it works? does the function will see the class inside it module?

And more generally Could I import some function of my package inside my namespace. I though it was done this way and answer I got from internet doesn't really help me.

Comment: see if my answer helps

Comment: if it answered your question, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the function `blast.foo()` would know and find the class `Blast`.

Whenever you import a module, in part or in its entirety, the entire module is loaded - the way you import it merely decides on what classes and functions are available in the current scope, and in what way.

For example, if you call this:

```
from package.blast import foo
```

only the function `foo()` would be available, but the entire package read and loaded. if you were to try instantiate the class `Blast` by itself in the same script, this would not work.

By the way, you can make importing functions more convenient, if you customize `__init__.py`. In your case, if you were to edit it like so:

```
>>>__init__.py
from blast.py import Blast, foo
```

you can import both function and class like so:

```
from package import Blast, foo
```

The reason why you `__all__` parameter does not work, is because it requires another import statement - mainly this:

```
from package import *
```

Calling this with your current `__init__.py` should work as expected.

Perhaps [this post by Mike Grouchy](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html) is able to clarify things a bit more.

Comment: more clear explanation than most thing find on internet thanks.